# Getting dependent records in $dataProvider variable

Tags: php, yii

i have two tables  tbl_entries and tbl_votings

```
tbl_entries -> id, othercolums
tbl_votings -> id, entry_id, othercolumns
```

i want to show data in zii.widgets.CListView from the tbl_entries if users have voted for the entries.

i am able to run below sql query successfully.

```
select * from tbl_entries where id in (select tbl_entries.id from tbl_votings where entry_id = tbl_entries.id )
```

how can i do in YII style so that i can show result in CListView?

Answer (score 1):

in `Entries` model add relation:

```
...
'votes' => array(self::HAS_MANY, 'Votings', 'entry_id'),
...
```

Then search via AR:

```
$records = Entries::model()->with('votes')->findAll();
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: i used your solution. $dataProvider = Entries::model()->with('votes')->findAll(); to put  in CListView but it gives error "Fatal error: Call to a member function getData() on a non-object in..."

Answer (score 0):

**Updated**

Ok, i missed word "if" in your post, and thought you need entries ONLY if users voted for it. Read update below for right code. I leave you the first part just in case you need it in the future. INNER JOIN will take entries ONLY if that entries have at least 1 vote.

------------------ FIRST PART (wrong) --------------------

Declare a relation inside your `Entries` model:

```
public function relations() {
    return array(
        'votes' => array(self::HAS_MANY, 'Votings', 'entry_id'),
    );
```

}

And when you create your data provider do it like this:

```
$dataProvider = new CActiveDataProvider('Entries',
    array(
        'criteria' => array(
            'with' => array(
                'votes'=>array(
                    'joinType' => 'INNER JOIN'
                )
            )
        )
    )
);
```

This will not create you the SQL you have written above, but this will do it the right way.
The SQL will look similar to this:

```
select * from tbl_entries t INNER JOIN tbl_votings v ON t.id = v.entry_id
```

----------------- SECOND PART (right) ------------------

**Update**

Ok, so if you simply need to get entries and votes for them you do the same relation declaration from first part:

```
public function relations() {
    return array(
        'votes' => array(self::HAS_MANY, 'Votings', 'entry_id'),
    );
```

}

And you create your data provider like this:

```
$dataProvider = new CActiveDataProvider('Entries',
    array(
        'criteria' => array(
            'with' => array('votes')
        )
    )
);
```